# How to save single sheet, as separate file in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

When I have multiple sheeet in LibreOffice document, how to save specific sheet as new .ods file in LibreOffice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right-click the name of the Sheet and select **Move/Copy Sheet...**

[image: right-click options]

This would open a dialog window where you can specify the Location where you want the Sheet to be moved/copied. You may also move the sheet to another existing document — to do that, ensure to simultaneously open that existing document as well.

[image: Move/Copy Sheet dialog window]